# TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, lstm

Hello I do not understand why i get the error as shown in title with the following as my forward propagation function

```
    # For function that will activate neurons and perform forward propagation
def forward(self, inputs):
    state, (hx, cx) = inputs # getting separately the input images to the tuple (hidden states, cell states)
    x = F.relu(self.lstm(state)) # forward propagating the signal from the input images to the 1st convolutional layer
    hx, cx = self.lstm(x, (hx, cx)) # the LSTM takes as input x and the old hidden & cell states and ouputs the new hidden & cell states
    x = hx # getting the useful output, which are the hidden states (principle of the LSTM)
    return self.fcL(x), (hx, cx) # returning the output of the actor (Q(S,A)), and the new hidden & cell states ((hx, cx))
```

and this as my action_selection function:

```
    def select_action(self, state):
    #LSTM
    initialise = True # Initialise to zero at first iteration
    if initialise:
        cx = Variable(torch.zeros(1, 30))
        hx = Variable(torch.zeros(1, 30))
    else:  # The hx,cx from the previous iteration
        cx = Variable(cx.data) 
        hx = Variable(hx.data) 
    initialise = False
    q_values, (hx,cx) = self.model(Variable(state), (hx,cx))
    probs = F.softmax((q_values)*self.tau,dim=1)
    #create a random draw from the probability distribution created from softmax
    action = probs.multinomial()
    return action.data[0,0]
```

Comment: None of this code ever calls the `forward` function.

Comment: fix your indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you use your forward-function? Meaning in which line does it throw the error? I can't find it.

But in general: If you use the function forward not inside your class, but as an object it actually takes one argument. (self is given "automatically", so you can reference inside the class to other stuff. For better explanation just read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html ). So for example if you try to do something like this:

```
myObject = myClass()
myObject.forward(a,b)
```

it will throw exactly this error

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same non descriptive issue, and did not call the forward function outside the class as answer before stated. After a while i found it was the second value i added to multiple declarations of 'x' variable i had in forward function, because i wanted to create a cuda tensor. I know this is an old question, but it just might help someone who stumbles upon it.
Check your x variables under forward function as they should not take more than one argument.

Comment: Forward function is automatically invoked in pytorch, when you pass tensor to Model, except your explicit needs, this is because of pytorch Object Oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this error because I defined `self.fc = nn.Linear(2,1)` and then had `forward(self,x1,x2)` and expected `self.fc(x1,x2)` to do concatenation of `x1` and `x2` for me, now hilarious but spent hours before I figured my mistake. Had the issue because I initially started with a model of a scalar input and was trying to adapt the code to a model with length 2 input vector.